# What is more effective, generate whole elements or swap the content?

Tags: html, angular

I create flashcards, project is written in angular 2. Whats is more effective, after clickin button(card fades out and hide) and content is replacing and div appears(using data from json) or generating 10 flashards from a json and hide them and show them in right order?

Answer (score 1):

Create one card and change the content, the fewer amount of `data-bindings` the better. This approach also makes you application more scalable in the future. Also use `*ngIf` to hide and show the card so the actual HTML is destroyed and not just hidden which again lowers the `data-bindings`.

Comment: I guess the easiest for you is just to follow the tutorial of angular. https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/. You find a lot of tutorials online